# Is it possible to hide backfaces when using SwiftUI rotation3DEffect?

Tags: ios, 3d, swiftui

Consider this simple example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RotationExample: View {

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.red
      Text("Text I want to hide")
      .font(.system(size: 48))
    }
    .frame(width: size, height: size)
    .rotation3DEffect(Angle.degrees(180), axis: (x: 0, y:1, z: 0))
  }
}

struct RotationExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    RotationExample()
  }
}
```

When this code is run, the text is shown reversed. I thought when the rotation was applied, the layers would be respected (ie. the foreground layer would disappear behind the background)

[image: Screenshot showing red rectangle with 'Text I want to hide' backwards on top]

Is it possible to hide a View when it is a backface rotated beyond 90 degrees, or to somehow get the layers to reverse during rotation? I have tried using `.drawingGroup()` and setting `.background` modifiers but neither worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using computed properties it's possible to determine whether the layer should be shown or not - this allows for continous adjustments like the following where the rotation is on a drag gesture. The angle of rotation is based on the gesture, then the opacity is based on the angle:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RotationExample: View {

  @State var translation: CGSize = .zero

  var textOpacity: Double {
    let theta: Double = abs(angle.degrees).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
    return theta >= 90 && theta <= 270 ? 0 : 1
  }

  var textOpacity: Double {
    return abs(angle.degrees) >= 90 ? 0 : 1
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.red

      Text("Text I want to hide")
      .font(.system(size: 48))
      .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      .opacity(textOpacity)
    }
    .frame(width: size, height: size)
    .rotation3DEffect(angle, axis: (x: 0, y:1, z: 0))
    .gesture(DragGesture()
      .onChanged { value in
        self.translation = value.translation
      })
  }
}

struct RotationExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    RotationExample()
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not run anymore as angel is not in scope, textOpacity is being redeclared

Answer (score 1):

The `rotation3DEffect` is just a transformation to drawing context, ie. *how to draw content*, there is no any *backface*. If you want to draw different content then you have to provide it explicitly, like in below example.

```
struct RotationExample: View {
    @State private var flipped = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Flip") { self.flipped.toggle() }
            ZStack {
                if flipped {   // 1st-side content
                    Color.red
                    Text("Text I want to hide")
                        .font(.system(size: 48))
                    .rotation3DEffect(Angle.degrees(180), axis: (x: 0, y:1, z: 0))
                } else {       // 2nd-side content
                    Color.blue
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, o master of Swift :)