# SwiftUI: How to switch only first item of an array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on iOS App with a card-swipe function like Tinder. I have an array with  cards. I want to integrate the possibility to flip the card to get more information.

```
struct TryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cards = APIObs()
    @State var back = false
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader{geo in
            ZStack{
                ForEach(cards.shows){ i in
                    ZStack{
                        if back == false{
                        
                        SwipeDetailsView1(name: i.name, age: i.status, image: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500\(i.image)", height: geo.size.height-80, info: $back) .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.back ? 180.0 : 0.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0))
                            .zIndex(self.back ? 0 : 1)
                     
                        }else{
                        BackView(name: i.name, height: geo.size.height-80, info: $back) .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.back ? 0.0 : 180.0), axis: (x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0))
                            .zIndex(self.back ? 1 : 0)
                            
                        }
                    }.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.25))
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Problem is, that when `back == true` all cards of the array flip. I just want the first one to flip. Does anyone know how to manage that?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61627329/12299030?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your `@State var back` is for the array.

If you want to control each card you need a `CardView` with an `@State var back` for each card.

I put some sample code below. A minimum reproducible example is preferred so we don't have to recreate `struct`'s and other components

```
import SwiftUI

struct TryView: View {
    //@ObservedObject var cards = APIObs()//Code not Provided
    @State var cards = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie"]
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader{geo in
            VStack{
                ForEach(cards, id: \.self){ i in
                    CardView(card: i)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SwipeDetailsView1: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}
struct BackView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @State var back = false //Variable for just the card
    var card: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                if back == false{
                    
                    SwipeDetailsView1(name: "front \(card)")
                    
                }else{
                    BackView(name: "back \(card)")
                    
                }
            }.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.25))
            Button("flip", action: {
                back.toggle()
            })
        }
        
    }
}
struct TryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TryView()
    }
}
```